# How to prevent VS Code from auto-deleting tabs on an empty line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs

When I use some tabs on a line without any text，VS Code always auto deletes my tabs.

How to prevent this VSCode action?

[image: Here is the state]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a checkbox option in VSCode settings called **Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace** and **Files: Trim Trailing Whitespace**

If you uncheck that then it should stop

Comment: json value is  "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false,

Answer (score 0):

Open VS Code Settings > Extensions > Dart&Flutter. Then uncheck "Dart:Enable SDK Formatter".